# How to mix the outliers (from boxplot or not) with violin plot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

The graphs.

[image: like this boxplot and violin plot]

[image: my violin plot]

The first graph is captured from https://towardsdatascience.com/violin-plots-explained-fb1d115e023d. And the second one is created by myself.

I found this requirement when I was doing my python matplotlib assignment since the professor required us to highlight the outliers on violin plot whether they existed.

For the violin plot I created, there is no y values, or in other words, the y values are empty even I use python commander instead of jupyter notebook for when I pause my mouse on the graph, there is only x value, but the y value is “y = ”. There is no way for me if I want to plot circles to highlight the outliers since there are only x values.

Moreover, I created violin plot by using seaborn library.

Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bit unclear how exactly you created the [violinplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html).  In general, the non-numeric axes are [categorical](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html) and numbered internally as `0, 1, 2, ...`. So, `y` would be `0` here.

[Outliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier) can be defined in many ways, for a standard [boxplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) the whiskers are drawn at 1.5 times the distance between the first and third quartile.

Note that a boxplot shows the data "as is", while a violinplot smooths out the data. Depending on the distribution it could give the impression of data being at places where they would be impossible in practice (e.g. negative values for a height). Which one to prefer in a given situation depends on many factors, but it is important to understand the limitations of each.

Seaborn also has a [boxenplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxenplot.html), similar to a boxplot, but showing many more of the quantiles. And there is [swarmplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html), which draws all the points, but pushes them away to avoid overlap. If there are too many points, you might want to limit the swarmplot to a subset. A swarmplot can also be combined with e.g. a boxplot to show extra information. Or instead of the scatterplot to show outliers.

The following plot compares a default boxplot with a violinplot, showing the outliers in red and a boxenplot:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(553)
data = np.random.randn(6, 500).cumsum(axis=1).ravel()
q1, q3 = np.percentile(data, [25, 75])
whisker_low = q1 - (q3 - q1) * 1.5
whisker_high = q3 + (q3 - q1) * 1.5
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 6), sharex=True)
sns.boxplot(x=data, color='CornflowerBlue', ax=ax1)
sns.violinplot(x=data, color='CornflowerBlue', ax=ax3)
outliers = data[(data > whisker_high) | (data < whisker_low)]
sns.scatterplot(x=outliers, y=0, marker='D', color='crimson', ax=ax3)
sns.boxenplot(x=data, color='CornflowerBlue', ax=ax2)
sns.swarmplot(x=data, color='CornflowerBlue', size=1.5, ax=ax4)
plt.setp((ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4), "yticks", [])
sns.despine(fig, top=True, left=True, right=True)
ax1.tick_params(labelbottom=True)
ax2.tick_params(labelbottom=True)
ax1.set_title('boxplot')
ax2.set_title('boxenplot')
ax3.set_title('violinplot with outliers')
ax4.set_title('swarmplot')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: violinplot with outliers, boxplot, boxenplot, swarmplot]

Comment: AWESOME! MY MAN!